# Eigenvectors of derivative

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I'm trying to consider how linear algebra relates to calculus.  It seems to me that the only eigenvectors of the derivative operator on $\Bbb R$ are the functions $ce^{kx}$ for constants $c$ and $k$.  The eigenvalues associated with these eigenspaces are $k$.  I'm not sure how to prove uniqueness of this, but these seem to be the only ones.

OK.  What about derivatives on $\Bbb R^n$?  $e^{\mathbf x}$ is not a thing because a power series of vectors $\mathbf x$ doesn't make sense (I think).  So what are the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the derivative in this case?

Are there any other interesting results from linear algebra that apply to calculus?

Comment: Are you familiar with theorems regarding the uniqueness of solutions to certain differential equations? If so, denoting the differential operator by $D$, the statement $Df=\lambda f$ is equivalent to the equation $f'=\lambda f$. In $\mathbb{R}^n$  the concept of the derivative is extended using the notion of a linear transformation.

Comment: I know that there *are* theorems for the existence and uniqueness of solutions to linear differential equations.  They weren't covered in my course on ODEs though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote the differential operator by $D$. The equation $Df=\lambda f$ is equivalent to $f'=\lambda f$. Multiplying by $e^{-\lambda x}$ we obtain:

$$f'(x)e^{-\lambda x}-e^{-\lambda x}\lambda f(x)=0$$

which is the same as

$$(f(x)e^{-\lambda x})'=0$$

Which means that there exists a constant $c$ such that

$$f(x)e^{-\lambda x}=c \ \text{for all $x$}$$

Hence $$f(x)=ce^{\lambda x}$$

as desired.

Regarding $\mathbb{R}^n$: Recall that a function $f:A \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ ($A$ open) is said to be differentiable at $x \in A$ if there exists a linear transformation, denoted by $Df(x)$ or $f'(x)$ such that:

$$\lim_{h \to 0}{\left \| f(x+h)-f(x)-(Df(x))(h) \right \| \over \left \| h \right \|}=0$$

Note that $Df(x)$ is **linear function** between $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$. Furthermore, $Df(x)$ is the only linear transformation which verifies the limit above.

As you can see the question $f=f'$ doesn't make as much sense in this context.

However, if we take a linear transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ and any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ it is easy to verify, by using the limit above, that:

$$T=T'(x)$$